# What is different between getCollection(); and $product->getData();

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, model

What is different between **getCollection();** and **$product->getData();**

```
$products_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
**getCollection();
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addFieldToFilter('price','5.00');
```

and

```
$product->getData();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name suggest - `getCollection()` returns a collection/list of many products by some criteria (`addFieldToFilter()`). getData() returns full data for specific product.

Answer (score 2):

getCollection() return the collection/list of products based on the filter given.

While in getData() its return the products data in an array based on the filter used on collection.

There is also one other method called getItems() it returns products object list.

getData() returns product data as an array while getItems() returns products objectlist.